# Pyspark: For each month, make a cumulative sum of the previous 3 months

Tags: pyspark, window, partition, cumulative-sum

I'm using PYSPARK and I'm trying to make a cumulative sum of the last 3 months from a specific month:

Example:

```
Month   Value
Jan/19    1
Feb/19    0
Mar/19    4
Apr/19    5
May/19    0
Jun/19   10
```

So the cumulative sum for each month on the previous months will be:

```
Month   Value
Jan/19    1
Feb/19  1 + 0 = 1
Mar/19  1+0+4 = 5
Apr/19  0+4+5 = 9
May/19  4+5+0 = 9
Jun/19  5+0+10 = 15
```

I'm pretty sure that I need to use window and partition functions but I have no idea how to set up this.

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks

Comment: are there multiple years(17,18,19) in the month column?

Comment: yea, it has from 2017 to 2019 but I don't think that this is an issue since I'd just need the main idea about partition and window

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Sample DataFrame:**

```
df.show()
+------+-----+
| Month|Value|
+------+-----+
|Jan/19|    1|
|Feb/19|    0|
|Mar/19|    4|
|Apr/19|    5|
|May/19|    0|
|Jun/19|   10|
+------+-----+
```

You can use **`window`** function, but you need to convert your **`month`** column to a proper **`timestamp`** format, and then cast that to **`long`** to compute **`range(3months)`** based on **`unix time`** or **`timestamp in seconds`**. You can partitionBy your grouping columns in your real data. (*86400 is 1 day in seconds*).

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w=Window().orderBy(F.col("Month").cast("long")).rangeBetween(-(86400*89), 0)
df\
.withColumn("Month", F.to_timestamp("Month","MMM/yy"))\
.withColumn("Sum", F.sum("Value").over(w)).show()

+-------------------+-----+---+
|              Month|Value|Sum|
+-------------------+-----+---+
|2019-01-01 00:00:00|    1|  1|
|2019-02-01 00:00:00|    0|  1|
|2019-03-01 00:00:00|    4|  5|
|2019-04-01 00:00:00|    5|  9|
|2019-05-01 00:00:00|    0|  9|
|2019-06-01 00:00:00|   10| 15|
+-------------------+-----+---+
```

If you would like to go back **`3 months only`** in **`each year`**. Meaning ***`Jan/19`*** will only have **`Jan/19`** value. For this case, you should use a **`partitionBy`** of **`Year`**, and **`orderBy month number`**, and **`rangeBetween -2 and 0.`**

```
w=Window().partitionBy(F.year("Month")).orderBy(F.month("Month")).rangeBetween(-2, 0)
df\
.withColumn("Month", F.to_timestamp("Month","MMM/yy"))\
.withColumn("Sum", F.sum("Value").over(w)).show()

+-------------------+-----+---+
|              Month|Value|Sum|
+-------------------+-----+---+
|2019-01-01 00:00:00|    1|  1|
|2019-02-01 00:00:00|    0|  1|
|2019-03-01 00:00:00|    4|  5|
|2019-04-01 00:00:00|    5|  9|
|2019-05-01 00:00:00|    0|  9|
|2019-06-01 00:00:00|   10| 15|
+-------------------+-----+---+
```